# Join tables to get grouped count for date range

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card_results` (
  `card_result_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`card_result_id`),
  KEY `created` (`created`),
  KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leads_result` (
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `aff_ref` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `lead_id` (`lead_id`),
  KEY `aff_id` (`aff_id`),
  KEY `lead_date` (`lead_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

What I need to get is someting like the below:

Count of all results in table leads_result
Count of all unique lead_id in table card_results
Grouped by aff_id

```
   aff_id   |   total_leads_result   |   total_card_results
--------------------------------------------------------------
    123     |          12            |            16   
    124     |          18            |            22   
    125     |          22            |            56   
    126     |          65            |            34   
    127     |          56            |            56
```

I have the below query but it is obviously missing rows where 
there are records in card_results but no records in leads_result 
for the given date

```
SELECT 
lr.aff_id,
COUNT(*) total_leads_result,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cr.lead_id) 
 FROM card_results cr2
 LEFT JOIN leads_result lr2 ON cr.lead_id = lr2.lead_id 
 WHERE lr2.aff_id = lr.aff_id
 AND DATE(created) = CURDATE() ) total_card_results
FROM leads_result lr
WHERE lead_date = CURDATE
GROUP BY lr.aff_id
```

I'm a little stumped. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: better give some sample data or a fiddle

Comment: `Schema Creation Failed: Key column 'aff_id' doesn't exist in table: `